# Is it possible to configure Anaconda Prompt to use different Shells?

Tags: windows-10, zsh, anaconda

Is it possible to configure [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) Prompt to use a different shell environment from the default installation on Windows-10?

I can't find any documenation specifying the Shell Anaconda Prompt uses, but it behaves like Windows `CMD.exe`. I'm more experienced with Bash and would prefer it, but even PowerShell would be an improvement.

I chose Anaconda to deploy my Python script on my work computer (this is a user install and not systmem-wide). I'm typically working in Windows GUI. When I need to use my Python Script, I need the CLI, and need to navigate directories, move & delete files.

I asked a *similar* question of the [Anaconda - public](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/bHUuOEGyF7Q) group, and [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) was a recommended direction. However, MSYS2 launches in it's own shell window, and so doesn't appear to have access to the Anaconda Python environment.

---

So far, I've been opening two terminals--Anaconda Prompt to exectue the script and WSL-Debian to perform file actions. This would be too complicated for some of my coleagues, and I wish to improve the CLI experience. But regardless, this is a CLI project.